# Change html page content

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I am creating Firefox addon using the Add-on SDK. I want to get data from remote url and inject it in current html. As of now i m able to fetch data using request module of Firefox addon sdk but m not able to inject it in current page.

for example : i am fetching response from website "abc.com".after fetching response i will augment current page with response

```
// main.js

var widgets = require("sdk/widget");
var tabs = require("sdk/tabs");
var Request = require("sdk/request").Request;

//create addon widget
var widget = widgets.Widget({
    id: "div-show",
    label: "Show divs",
    contentURL: "http://www.mozilla.org/favicon.ico",
    onClick: function() {
    //initializing request module to fetch content
    quijote.get();
    }
});

//fetch content of requested page
var quijote = Request({
    url: "http://localhost/abc/",
    overrideMimeType: "text/plain; charset=latin1",
    onComplete: function (response) {
        //check if content is fetched successfully 
        addContent(response);
    }
});

//try and modify current page
function addContent(response){
    //initialize page modification module
    var pageMod = require("sdk/page-mod");
    tabs.activeTab.attach({
       contentScript: 'document.body.innerHTML = ' + ' "<h1>'+response.text+'</h1>";'
    });
}
```

Is their any way in which i can augment my current page???

Comment: It is unclear to me what exactly is your goal here. Modify pages as they are loaded? Load some pages yourself and display those to the user? "Augment" pages by loading some additional html and inject that?

Comment: @nmaier : I want to fetch data from some remote website and show it to  user after augmenting current page.I have updated my question, please check it again

Comment: What's the problem you are having? Is than an error? Or is it just "my h1 doesn't appeare" when addcontent() is called?

Comment: when i use response.status it works find giving status as 200.also in i do console.log() on response.text it works fine but when i use response.text as shown above it gives me error stating "in null" error in terminal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code will bitterly fail e.g. when `response.text` includes a double quote.
Then your code would be (assume it is `<a href="hello">world</a>`):

```
document.body.innerHTML = "<h1><a href="hello">world</a></h1>";
```

This is obviously invalid code.

Your code basically constructs a dynamic script from unsanitized data, which is a bad idea because (other than the escaping problem above)

1. you'll be running an unsanitized content script if that code is even valid and
2. if that would succeed, the page might run unsanitized code as well.

This is the web equivalent to SQL injection attacks....

First, lets tackle 1.) with [messaging](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/modules/sdk/content/worker.html#Worker) ([more](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/dev-guide/guides/content-scripts/index.html)):

```
var worker = tabs.activeTab.attach({
   contentScript: 'self.port.on("setdom", function(data) { ' +
                    + 'document.body.innerHTML = data; /* still a security issue! */'
                    + '});'
});
worker.port.emit("setdom", response.text);
```

This guarantees that the content script will be valid (can even run) and does not run arbitrary code.

However 2.) is still a problem. Read [DOM Building and HTML insertion](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XUL/School_tutorial/DOM_Building_and_HTML_Insertion).

Comment: nmaier your code worked like charm. i read Dom build article can you tell me or give me reference link stating how to use that code in plugins

Comment: While most of the stuff in the article would also apply to regular websites, the article was already written with add-ons in mind.